# Why Static Member Pointer Is Zero In ELF Section?

Tags: c++, pointers, static, elf

Compile the following code, and retrieve the **.ippalgo** section, I notice that the `name` field is zero, while other fields are fine as expected.

```
$ g++ a.cpp
$ objdump -s -j .ippalgo a.out

a.out:     file format elf64-x86-64

Contents of section .ippalgo:
 601040 00000000 00000000 02000000 01000000  ................
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
$ ./a.out
sizeof(char*): 8, sizeof(int): 4
name: 0x400648
name: abcdef
```

But after change the *1.* line using `"abcdef"` string directly, I seems got the correct address.

```
$ objdump -s -j .ippalgo a.out

a.out:     file format elf64-x86-64

Contents of section .ippalgo:
 601040 08064000 00000000 02000000 01000000  ..@.............
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
$ ./a.out
sizeof(char*): 8, sizeof(int): 4
name: 0x400608
name: abcdef
```

In either case, the last print in main got correct message `abcdef`. My question is why I got zeros in the first case, and how to fix it if it's a problem?

```cpp
#include <cstdio>

struct DataInfo {
    const char* name;
    int id;
    int type;
};

class Proxy {
public:
    const static char *name;
    const static int type;
    const static int id;
};

const char* Proxy::name = "abcdef";
const int   Proxy::id = 1;
const int   Proxy::type = 2;

__attribute__((used, section(".ippalgo")))
DataInfo ProxyInfo = {
    Proxy::name,  // 1. ok when set "abcdef" directly
    Proxy::type,
    Proxy::id
};

int main()
{
    printf("sizeof(char*): %lu, sizeof(int): %lu\n",
           sizeof(char*), sizeof(int));
    printf("name: %p\n", Proxy::name);
    printf("name: %s\n", ProxyInfo.name);
}
```

Comment: Don't forget that `printf` is not type-safe, you need to use the exact correct format specifier for the matching argument, or you will have *undefined behavior*. Like you do in your code (`sizeof` returns a value of type `size_t`, which needs the `"%zu"` format specifier). Or better yet, use the type-safe `std::cout` for your output.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Good point, thank you.

Comment: To followers who have the same issue and doubt, take a look at this link: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initialization

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## TL;DR `Proxy::name` is not `const`.

---

There are two phases of initialization of static data: constant (including zero-initialization), and dynamic initialization.

Under certain conditions the two can be combined, and the final initializer places in the binary, instead of generating code to initialize it before `main()`.

Your compiler has chosen to use constant initialization in one case and dynamic initialization in the other.  This is perfectly legal, the compiler isn't ever required to place constants in any particular structure in the binary.

In your case, the fact that `Proxy::name` is not `const` as `Proxy::id` and `Proxy::type` are is probably influencing the compiler's choice.  It's not even a compile-time constant.  Maybe the compiler could prove that no other initialization code writes to `Proxy::name`, but this is non-trivial since `class Proxy` has external linkage.  So even constant propagation and application of the as-if rule fail you here.

`constexpr` would be even better at convincing the compiler to use constant initialization.  But you at least need to declare `Proxy::name` as `const`.

Comment: It worked after changing `name` declaration to `const static char * const name;`, I missed this part of knowledge before, thank you so much.